# Rails date format in a text_field

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a rails form that displays a date in a text_field:

```
<%= form.text_field :check_in_date  %>
```

The date is rendered as `yyyy-mm-dd`

I'm trying to figure out how to have it display as `mm-dd-yyyy`

I tried adding this config but it didn't work.

```
ActiveSupport::CoreExtensions::Date::Conversions::DATE_FORMATS.merge!(
  :default => '%m/%d/%Y'
)
```

Answer (score 65):

Simple one time solution is to use `:value` option within `text_field` call instead of adding something to `ActiveRecord::Base` or `CoreExtensions`.

For example:

```
<%= f.text_field :some_date, value: @model_instance.some_date.strftime("%d-%m-%Y") %>
```

Comment: Simple and direct. In my experience it's usually not worth fretting over adding some fancy code elsewhere - this has always been good enough for me.

Comment: This solution is good if you want to add value to the field in the edit method. But if you want to do this in _form.html.erb, it also works only in the edit method. Not in the new method - because you don't have the value.

Comment: Why is it so difficult to show a localized date value in a form ??

Answer (score 39):

I added these to my `initializers/time_formats.rb` and it works great:

```
# Default format for displaying dates and times
Date::DATE_FORMATS[:default] = "%m/%d/%Y"
Time::DATE_FORMATS[:default] = "%m/%d/%Y"
```

Using Ruby 1.9.3 and Rails 3.2.x

Comment: This seems like the cleanest and most simple method. I use this.

Comment: This is the best answer. The only trouble is you still need to parse the response in the controller and reformat it into a ruby parsable date.

Comment: You can use the american_date gem to make the parsing automatic: https://github.com/jeremyevans/ruby-american_date

Comment: Not working with PostgreSql in my Mac, but works with Linux and Oracle ¿?

Answer (score 12):

I spent some time looking in the code, and changing the DATE_FORMAT won't work because Rails never asks for the date format. Felix's solution of setting :value does work, but feels cumbersome: why should I have to set the value of date-specific textfields by hand? So this is a codesmell, and I wanted something better.

Here's my short solution, but then I'll explain it a bit because I'm hoping somebody else will write something better:

```
MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  # ...
  self.columns.each do |column|
    if column.type == :date
      define_method "#{column.name}_before_type_cast" do
        self.send(column.name).to_s
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Somewhat longer explanation:
When a textfield is setting the value attribute, it'll first look in the options hash (which is why Felix's solution works), but if it's not there, it'll call `form.object.check_in_date_before_type_cast`, which (after some method_missing magic) will call `form.object.attributes_before_type_cast['check_in_date']`, which will look up 'check_in_date' in the @attributes hash inside form.object. My *guess* is that the @attributes hash is getting the direct MySQL string representation (which follows the 'yyyy-mm-dd' format) before it gets wrapped in a Ruby object, which is why simply setting the DATE_FORMAT doesn't work by itself. So the dynamic method creation above creates methods for all date objects that actually perform the typecast, allowing you to format the date using `ActiveSupport::CoreExtensions::Date::Conversions::DATE_FORMATS[:default]`.

This feels a little dirty because the whole purpose of '_before_type_cast' is to avoid a typecast, and this is one of those "thar be dragons" monkeypatches. But still, from what I can tell, it feels like the best of what's around. Maybe somebody else can do a little more digging and find a better solution?

Comment: This is definitely a monkey patch but it certainly has the best results out of any.  Christ, one would think this would be easier than this.

Comment: FormBuilder reads from `sth_before_type_cast` for a reason. And the reason is that if user puts incorrect input (for example `'2010,10.10'`) we want to deal with that incorrect input. For instance: we can give (to user) an opportunity to fix it. I suppose in your solution incorrect user input will be lost `sth_before_type_cast` will result with `""` (empty string from nil). I will post as an answer another ugly monkeypatch solution.

Answer (score 9):

Expanding Kamil's answer a bit:  add the following method to application_helper.rb:

```
def date_mdY(date)
  if date.nil?
    ""
  else
    date.strftime("%m-%d-%Y")
  end
end
```

Then you can modify Kamil's answer slightly:

```
<%= f.text_field :some_date, :value => date_mdY(@model_instance.some_date) %>
```

Then you can use this helper method in any other view.

I'm using the jQuery datepicker and the date needed to be in a particular format in order for the default date to be set correctly.  Thanks for the answer Kamil!

Comment: One line method body: `date.nil? ? "" : date.strftime("%m-%d-%Y")`

Answer (score 9):

There are two parts to making this work, and a third part to make it all work well. If you just want to copy paste, go ahead and scroll to the end.

#### Part 1: Getting `Date` to format itself as desired

There are a bunch of [core extensions to Date in ActiveSupport](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/date/conversions.rb), but none of them create a new date class. If you're working with `Date`, which is what Rails returns when you have a `date` column in your database, the method converting that date into a string is `Date#to_formatted_s`. The `ActiveSupport` extensions add this method, and they alias the `to_s` method to it, so when you call `Date#to_s` (probably implicitly), you get `Date.to_formatted_s`.

There are two ways to change the format used by `to_formatted_s`:

1. Pass the name of the format you would like used (this arg will be used to lookup the format in `Date::DATE_FORMATS`).
2. Change the format that `:default` maps to. Since `to_formatted_s` sets a default value of `:default`, when you call `Date#to_s` without passing an argument you get format specified by `Date::DATE_FORMATS[:default]`. You can override the default on an application-wide basis like this:

   ```
   Date::DATE_FORMATS[:default] = "%m/%d/%Y"
   ```

I have this set in an initializer like `config/initializers/date_formats.rb`. It's crude and doesn't support changing with your localizations, but gets `Date#to_s` to return the desired format without any monkey patching or explicitly converting your dates to strings and passing in an argument.

### Part 2: Getting user-inputted dates converted to Date objects

By default, your `ActiveRecord` instance will [cast date columns](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activemodel/lib/active_model/type/date.rb) using good ol' ISO 8601 that looks like this: `yyyy-mm-dd`.

If it doesn't match that format exactly (e.g., it's slash delimited), it falls back to using Ruby's [Date._parse](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.1/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-c-_parse), which is a little more lenient, but still expects to see days, months, then years: `dd/mm/yyyy`.

To get Rails to parse the dates in the format you're collecting them, you just need to replace the `cast_value` method with one of your own. You *can* monkeypatch `ActiveRecord::Types::Date`, but it's not much harder to roll your own type inheriting from it.

I like using [Chronic](https://github.com/mojombo/chronic) to parse date strings from user input because it puts up with more shit, like "Tomorrow", or "Jan 1 99", or even bonkers input like "5/6-99" (May 6, 1999). Since Chronic returns an instance of `Time` and we're overriding the supplied `cast_value` method, we need to call `to_date` on it.

```
class EasyDate < ActiveRecord::Type::Date
  def cast_value(value)
    default = super
    parsed = Chronic.parse(value)&.to_date if value.is_a?(String)
    parsed || default
  end
end
```

Now we just need to tell ActiveRecord to use `EasyDate` instead of `ActiveRecord::Type::Date`:

```
class Pony < ApplicationRecord
  attribute :birth_date, EasyDate.new
end
```

That works, but if you're like me, you want to take on a bunch more work right now so you can save 3 seconds in the future. What if we could tell ActiveRecord to always use EasyDate for columns that are just dates? We can.

### Part 3: Make Rails handle this automatically

ActiveRecord gives you all sorts of information about your model that it uses to handle all of the “magic” behind the scenes. One of the methods it gives you us `attribute_types`. If you run that in your console, you get back vomit — it's kind of scary, and you just go “oh nevermind”. If you dig into that vomit like some sort of weirdo, though, it's just a hash that looks like this:

```
{ column_name: instance_of_a_type_object, ... }
```

Not scary stuff, but since we're starting to poke at internals, the inspected output of these `instance_of_a_type_object` can end up looking obtuse and “closed”. Like this:

```
#<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::PostgreSQL::OID::Money:0x007ff974d62688
```

Thankfully, we really only care about one: `ActiveRecord::Types::Date`, so we can narrow it down:

```
date_attributes = attribute_types.select { |_, type| ActiveRecord::Type::Date === type }
```

That gives us a list of the attributes that we want to upcycle to use `EasyDate`. Now we just need to tell ActiveRecord to use EasyDate on those attributes like we did above:

```
date_attributes.each do |attr_name, _type|
  attribute attr_name, EasyDate.new
end
```

And that basically does it, but we need to glue it all together. If you're using `ApplicationRecord` you can drop this right into it and be off to the races:

```
def inherited(klass)
  super
  klass.attribute_types.select { |_, type| ActiveRecord::Type::Date === type }.each do |name, _type|
    klass.attribute name, EasyDate.new
  end
end
```

If you don't want to “pollute” `ApplicationRecord`, you can do like I did and create a module and extend `ApplicationRecord` with it. If you're *not* using `ApplicationRecord`, you'll need to create the module and extend `ActiveRecord::Base`.

```
module FixDateFormatting
  # the above `inherited` method here
end

# Either this...
class ApplicationRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend FixDateFormatting
end

# ...or this:
ActiveRecord::Base.extend(FixDateFormatting)
```

## TL;DR — What to copy paste

If you aren't concerned with the *how* and just want this to work, you can:

1. Add `gem "chronic"` to your Gemfile and `bundle install`
2. Make sure your models inherit from `ApplicationRecord`
3. Copy the code below a file at `config/initializers/date_formatting.rb`
4. Restart
5. Everything should now Just Work™

Here's the code to copy:

```
Date::DATE_FORMATS[:default] = "%m/%d/%Y"

module FixDateFormatting
  class EasyDate < ActiveRecord::Type::Date
    def cast_value(value)
      default = super
      parsed = Chronic.parse(value)&.to_date if value.is_a?(String)
      parsed || default
    end
  end

  def inherited(subclass)
    super
    date_attributes = subclass.attribute_types.select { |_, type| ActiveRecord::Type::Date === type }
    date_attributes.each do |name, _type|
      subclass.attribute name, EasyDate.new
    end
  end
end

Rails.application.config.to_prepare do
  ApplicationRecord.extend(FixDateFormatting)
end
```

Answer (score 7):

## config/initializers/date_format.rb

```
ActiveSupport::CoreExtensions::Date::Conversions::DATE_FORMATS[:default] = '%m/%d/%Y'
```

## view

```
<%= form.text_field :check_in_date, value: model.check_in_date.to_s %>
```

Answer (score 6):

This one use location, in your form:

```
<%= f.text_field :date3, value: ( l @model.date3 if @model.date3? ) %>
```

In locations en.yml (or es.yml)

```
en:
  date:
    formats:
      default: "%d/%m/%Y"
```

Comment: This is a great way to get the date to display correctly. But it will not change how a date input is parsed. For example, if I set `default: "%m/%d/%Y"` in `en.yml`, it will still parse `check_in_date = "02/06/2020"` as `Date(2020, 6, 2)` instead of `Date(2020, 2, 6)`

Answer (score 2):

My preferred way of handling this is with **virtual attributes**. There's a short [RailsCast on the subject](http://railscasts.com/episodes/16-virtual-attributes) (3m), but the upshot is that virtual attributes will allow you to use a non-standard format when displaying model attributes in a form, or vice versa (*i.e.,* saving form data to a model).

Basically, rather than creating a form field for the `check_in_date` attribute, you can define a “virtual attribute” on the model:

```
class Reservation
  def check_in_date_string
    check_in_date.strftime('%m-%d-%Y')
  end

  def check_in_date_string=(date_string)
    self.check_in_date = Date.strptime(date_string, '%m-%d-%Y')
  end
end
```

Now, you can create form fields that correspond to `check_in_date_string` rather than `check_in_date`:

```
<%= f.text_field :check_in_date_string %>
```

That's it! No need to explicitly specify a `value` option, and when this form is submitted, the model will be updated appropriately.

Comment: I love how simple this looks, but there were some gotchas in the implementation. This raises errors if (1) `check_in_date` is ever `nil` and (2) if `check_in_date_string` is ever set to a string that doesn't parse (i.e. `check_in_date_string = '2/30/2020'`). Note that an invalid string will raise an exception rather than adding a validation error and this doesn't allow you to set a value and run validation on it (as one normally does with attributes prior to validation).

Answer (score 2):

For people interested to format in a specific location and not all over the project, several answers advised to check if null and I want to add that using **try** with **strftime** will help to make it shorter.

```
            <%= f.fields_for :assets_depreciations do |asset| %>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <%= asset.text_field :depreciation_date, value: asset.object.depreciation_date.try(:strftime, "%d-%m-%Y") %>
                </td>
              </tr>
            <% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Go to your environment.rb file and add the following:

```
ActiveSupport::CoreExtensions::Date::Conversions::DATE_FORMATS.merge!(
  :default => '%m-%d-%Y' )
```

Check the [official](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/CoreExtensions/Time/Conversions.html) documentation if you feel like reading more :)

Comment: I'm not sure if this answer ever reflected what was in Rails, but today there is no such constant as `ActiveSupport::CoreExtensions` and your doc link is broken.

Answer (score 1):

So I did something like this in the model.

```
def start_date
  super.strftime "%Y/%m/%d %H:%M"
end
```

Say you have a column called `start_date` in model, and want to display another format in the form, just overwrite its value in model.

And nothing needs to be changed in the form.

```
<%= f.text_field :start_date, class: 'form-control' %>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can set the value manually you can use **created_at.strftime("%m-%d-%Y")** http://snippets.dzone.com/tag/strftime .

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problems with time attributes/fields. So one can follow this:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/32-time-in-text-field

And it works pretty well.

But I dug into and found another interesting solution. Kind of a ugly monkeypatch, but in some cases it could be more useful that the one from railscasts.

So I have a model with a column named `time` (ofc it has a time type). Here is my solution:

```
  after_initialize :init

  private
  def init
    unless time.nil?
      @attributes['time'] = I18n.l(time, format: :short)
    end
  end
```

As you can see I format the variable which going to be returned by `time_before_type_cast` method. So I have properly formatted time in my text input (rendered by `FormBuilder`), but if user puts something wrong like `10;23` I still have this and in next request it will be rendered by `FormBuilder::text_field`. So user has an opportunity to fix his miserable mistake.

Comment: Maybe I should mention that `@attributes` is a hash with attributes before type cast and `@attributes_cache` is a hash with "real" attributes values.

Answer (score 0):

A slight improvement of Tom Rossis answer is to use the `I18n.localize` method, so the default will always be in the current users locale:

`initializers/date_time_i18n_formatter.rb`

```
Date::DATE_FORMATS[:default] = ->(date) { I18n.localize date, format: :default }
Time::DATE_FORMATS[:default] = ->(time) { I18n.localize time, format: :default }
```