# Rails 3.1 text_field form helper and jQuery datepicker date format

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a form field in my Rails view like this:

```
<%= f.text_field :date, :class => "datepicker" %>
```

A javascript function converts all input fields of that class to a jQueryUI datepicker.

```
$(".datepicker").datepicker({
                dateFormat : "dd MM yy",
                buttonImageOnly : true,
                buttonImage : "<%= asset_path('iconDatePicker.gif') %>",
                showOn : "both",
                changeMonth : true,
                changeYear : true,
                yearRange : "c-20:c+5"
            })
```

So far so good. I can edit the record and it persists the date correctly all the way to the DB. My problem is when I want to edit the record again. When the form is pre-populated from the record it displays in 'yyyy-mm-dd' format. The javascript only formats dates which are selected in the datepicker control. Is there any way I can format the date retrieved from the database? At which stage can I do this?

Thanks,
Dany.

Some more details following the discussion below, my form is spread across two files, a view and a partial. Here's the view:

```
<%= form_tag("/shows/update_individual", :method => "put") do %>
    <% for show in @shows %>
        <%= fields_for "shows[]", show do |f| %>
            <%= render "fields", :f => f %>
        <% end %>
    <% end %>
    <%= submit_tag "Submit"%>
<% end %>
```

And here's the `_fields` partial view:

```
<p>
    <%= f.label :name %>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
</p>

<p>
    <%= f.date %>
    <%= f.label :date %>
    <%= f.text_field :date, :class => "datepicker" %>
</p>
```

Controller code:

```
def edit_individual
    @shows = Show.find(params[:show_ids])
  end
```

I have added the following in `environment.rb`:

```
Date::DATE_FORMATS.merge!(
  :default => "%d %B %Y"
)
```

Now it's displaying the right format when I use @show.date in the view, but the form helper is still displaying the raw format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SOLVED: I pass in the `:value => show.date` as suggested by Jayendra above. The reason it wasn't working was because I didn't pass in the `show` object from the parent view. I changed the `render` line to include it - the parent view now looks like this:

```
<%= form_tag("/shows/update_individual", :method => "put") do %>
    <% for show in @shows %>
        <%= fields_for "shows[]", show do |f| %>
            <%= render "fields", :f => f, :show => show %>
        <% end %>
    <% end %>
    <%= submit_tag "Submit"%>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 12):

JQuery datepicker won't format the pre-populated date.
You would need to handle it on the rails side by using the formatted date with the textfield, instead of the raw date which has the default 'yyyy-mm-dd' format.

Example -

```
<%= f.text_field :date, :class => "datepicker", :value => @model.date.strftime("%d %m %Y") %>
```

More examples @ [Rails date format in a text_field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1449955/rails-date-format-in-a-text-field)

Comment: Yup, I realised that but I'm not sure how to format the date as it comes out of the DB...

Comment: added an example. There would be more elegant methods to handle it on helper or model side.

Comment: I'm getting an error since `@date` is nil. How do I get hold of the record currently referenced by the form helper?

Comment: @date was an example. You would probably have the model object "@model.date" which you would need to use. Would need to check for nil before using the strtime method. Added a method formatteddate to the model itself which does the above.

Comment: I tried `@model` but that didn't work, I got `undefined method `date' for #<ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder:0x000001052b5f38>`. Have also tried @model_instance to no avail...

Comment: whats the model object you have in your controller. You would need to use that object. Suppose this form is for user and your controller has "@user" shared, you would need to use "@user.date".

Comment: I have added a bit more details in the question. I tried using @show but that didn't work either...

Comment: Thanks! I think using rails I18n is more consistent like l(@model.date, format: ...)

Answer (score 1):

What I ended up doing is to just create a normal text input and prepopulate it with an ISO formatted date and additional information to mark it as a date input (say, rel="date").

On the client side, I have JavaScript to create a new hidden input that takes on the name of the original field (thus overriding it, for good measure I also delete the name property of the original). The datepicker is attached to the original field, and uses altField/altFormat to sync the hidden field with an ISO date.

```js
// used in jQuery's .each
function create_datepicker_for(_, el) {
  var e = $(el),
      mirror,
      date;

  // attach a hidden field that mirrors the proper date
  mirror = $('<input type="hidden"></input>')
           .prop('name', e.prop('name'))
           .insertAfter(e);

  if (e.val()) { date = new Date(e.val()); }

  e
  .prop('name', '')       /* make sure this is not sent to the application */
  .datepicker({
    altField: mirror,     /* "mirror" is the hidden field */
    altFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' /* you do not want anything but ISO */
  });

  if (date) { e.datepicker('setDate', date) }
}
```

This appears to keep everything in sync, sends the proper date format to the application, and degrades as well as anyone would expect it to.

Answer (score 0):

if your are using mysql database you can format the date in query itself.

Sample code

```
     date_format(date_field,"%d %m %y")
```