# datepicker doesn't save date

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datepicker, has-many-through

I have a join table `Writing` between tables `User` and `Exercise`. My model is

```
class Writing < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :exercise
    attr_accessible :writing_date, :exercise_id
end
```

I followed this [Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) for The has_many :through Association

and my table born in

```
class CreateWritings < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :writings do |t|
      t.integer :user_id
      t.integer :exercise_id
      t.date :writing_date
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
  def self.down
    drop_table :writings
  end
end
```

my writings_controller is:

```
 # encoding: utf-8
 class WritingsController < ApplicationController
    def create
        @writing = current_user.writings.build(:exercise_id => params[:exercise_id], :writing_date => params[:writing_date])
       if @writing.save
            flash[:notice] = "added writing."
            redirect_to root_url
       else
            flash[:error] = "not added."
            redirect_to root_url
       end
    end
    def new
       @writing = current_user.writings.new
       @exercise = Exercise.all
       respond_to do |format|
          format.html # new.html.erb
          format.xml  { render :xml => @writing }
       end
    end
end
```

and my _form.html.erb is like

```
 <%= form_for(@writing) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
   <%= f.text_field :writing_date %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "add a writing", :class => "awesome custom red" %>
  </div>
 <% end %>
```

The problem? The data is not saving from writing_date to database. I am using jQuery and datepicker.
I followed the logs

```
Started POST "/writings" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-05-19 19:55:23 +0300
  Processing by WritingsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"q3xXMxVd9PsI346ph9CILLm8x74uCFokz3/2yOA0CeI=", "exercise_id"=>"7", "writing"=>{"writing_date"=>"2012-05-19"}, "commit"=>"add a writing"}
```

everything ok but ...

```
AREL (0.3ms)  INSERT INTO "writings" ("user_id", "exercise_id", "writing_date", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (1, 7, NULL, '2012-05-19 16:55:23.719410', '2012-05-19 16:55:23.719410')
```

`writing_date` is null.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to configure datepicker to another format. For example:

```
$(".datepicker").datepicker({
            dateFormat : "dd MM yy"
});
```

Ruby date formats can be found here: http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html
And related question: [Rails 3.1 text_field form helper and jQuery datepicker date format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8103323/rails-3-1-text-field-form-helper-and-jquery-datepicker-date-format)

Comment: thanks for reply, I have already configure my file public/javascripts/application.js like this "dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd". I change to "dateFormat: "dd MM yy" but with no luck.

Comment: Ok, sorry :) And now can you try this: `@writing = current_user.writings.build(:exercise_id => params[:exercise_id], :writing_date => params[:writing][:writing_date])` ? Because in your params you have: `"writing"=>{"writing_date"=>"2012-05-19"}`

Answer (score 0):

As per your parameters, `"writing"=>{"writing_date"=>"2012-05-19"}`, `"writing_date"` is under the `"writing"` hash, but you are passing the `params[:writing_data]` parameter only; that's why it is not working.

```ruby
@writing = current_user.writings.build(:exercise_id => params[:exercise_id], :writing_date => params[:writing_date])
```

> instead of params[:writing_date] you should use
>   params[:writing][:writing_date]

So you have to change it in the following way:

```ruby
@writing = current_user.writings.build(:exercise_id => params[:exercise_id], :writing_date => params[:writing][:writing_date])
```