# Rails - format date_field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, date

how can I style the date format of a date_field?

I got the following form:

```
<%= form_for([@user, @vehicle]) do |f| %>
    <%= f.label :name, "Vehicle name" %>
    <%= f.text_field :name, class: 'form-control' %>
    <%= f.label :matriculation_date %>
    <%= f.date_field :matriculation_date, class: 'form-control' %>
    <%= f.submit "Add", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

this is rendering the following HTML for the date field:

`<input class="form-control" type="date" name="vehicle[matriculation_date]" id="vehicle_matriculation_date">`

The date field accept input in the following format: `mm/dd/yyyy`. I want it to accept format like `dd/mm/yyyy`.

I tried to edit it.yml file without any luck.

```
it:
  date:
      formats:
        default: ! '%d/%m/%Y'

  datetime:
      formats:
        default: ! '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M'
```

Any clue? Thank you

### EDIT

None of the proposed solutions solve my problem, so I think my question was not very clear. What I want is just to style how the date_field prompt the user (see image for more details). At the moment the form show `mm/dd/yyyy`, and I want it to show `dd/mm/yyyy`.

Not sure it might be a useful information, but I'm using Bootstrap for styling.

[image]

Comment: Perhaps this may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1449955/rails-date-format-in-a-text-field. Note the pro and cons when it comes to saving the values.

Comment: If this is a problem of which input it accepts, I would imagine that has to do with the browsers locale and what is the standard date notation for that locale.  This SO post seems to re-inforce this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3496241/specifying-the-value-output-of-of-an-html5-input-type-date

Comment: well, I thought the same, and that's why I tried to edit the it.yml file, but I had no luck with it

Answer (score 14):

You can do:

```
<%= f.date_field :matriculation_date, as: :date, value: f.object.try(:strftime,"%m/%d/%Y"), class: 'form-control' %>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
@yourdate.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")
```

this works!

Comment: I've not such variable in my code, can you pls add more info? I do not want to style a date, I want to style the date_field input in the form. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the date formate with `strftime()`

```
@date.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
```

It will convert your date into `dd/mm/yyyy` formate as you wanted.
Here I am showing you an example:

```
t = Time.now
=> 2016-04-28 16:09:42 -0700
>> t.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
=> "28/04/2016"
```

for more `strftime()` formatting options you can check this http://apidock.com/ruby/DateTime/strftime

---

**EDIT :**

After reading your comment and screenshot i've got the solution as follow.

You can also use this gem: https://github.com/Nerian/bootstrap-datepicker-rails
on your gemfile.rb

```
gem 'bootstrap-datepicker-rails'
```

**then bundle install and restart rails server**

then add this line to **app/assets/stylesheets/application.css**

```
*= require bootstrap-datepicker
```

and add this line to **app/assets/javascripts/application.js**

```
//= require bootstrap-datepicker
```

and to use this in your form:

```
<%= f.date_field :matriculation_date, :id => "datepicker" %>
```

**and add this javascript on the same view of your form**

```
<script>
$('#datepicker').datepicker({format: 'dd/mm/yyyy'});
</script>
```

Comment: I've not such variable in my code, can you pls add more info? I do not want to style a date, I want to style the date_field input in the form. Thank you!

Comment: @davideghz I have edited my answer after checking your comment & screenshot. Hope it will solve your issue.

Comment: Hi Dharmesh, thank you very much. Anyway the datepicker just skip the problem and does not solve it to the root. I removed my last edit where I speak about datepicker, since I think it can be misleading. The original issue with date_field is still open :)

Answer (score 0):

My answer is based on @Dharmesh_Rupani answer

Follow the steps to add the `gem 'bootstrap-datepicker-rails'`

I made two little changes on the form

```
<%= f.text_field : matriculation_date, :placeholder => 'dd/mm/yyyy', class: 'form-control datepicker' %>
```

The first thing is I changed the type of the field to text, because when I implemented I had two calendars, one from the date_field and another from the new gem

The other thing I changed is instead of `:id` I used `:class`, because it may happen that you have more than one date field

lastly, you should add this on the view

```
<script>
  $( document ).ready(function() {
    $('.datepicker').datepicker({format: 'dd/mm/yyyy'});
  });
</script>
```