# How to change date format in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

I am trying to change date format for `date_field_tag`, but i am not getting proper.

code i have used:

```
<%= date_field_tag 'dob' , '' , value: @search_params[:dob], placeholder: 'YYYY/MM/DD', autocomplete: 'off', class: 'form-control' %>
```

i need to display format and save `yyyy/mm/dd`

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36926588/rails-format-date-field

Comment: On a side note don't use placeholders for this. https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2018/06/placeholder-attribute/#cognition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<%= date_field_tag 'dob', @search_params[:dob].to_date.strftime("%Y/%m/%d"),  placeholder: 'YYYY/MM/DD' %>
```

Note that date_field_tag method signature [helper's signature](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1.7/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-date_field_tag) is `date_field_tag(name, value = nil, options = {})`