# Creating rails object with date attribute passed in "%m/%d/%Y" format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my `_form.html.erb` I have a date picker that passes the selected date to the server in the format of `%m/%d/%Y`.  Example: "05/30/2016".

Within the `create` action when I instantiate the object with the passed in params: Rails does not understand how to initialize the date attribute based on the format the date is passed in through the parameters, so it just sets the date attribute to nil.
Example:

```
#blogs_controller.rb
class BlogsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @blog = Blog.new(blog_params) # does not understand how to initialize the some_date attribute based on the format it is passed in as, so it initializes the some_date attribute to nil
    @blog.save
    redirect_to some_path
  end 

  private

  def blog_params
    params.require(:blog).permit(:some_date)
  end
end
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1449955/rails-date-format-in-a-text-field) suggests to create an initializer file that makes it so that rails will understand that format when it is passed into the parameters, but it did not work for me.  It is still initializing the date to nil:

```
#initializers/date_format.rb
Date::DATE_FORMATS[:default] = "%m/%d/%Y"
```

I also tried this in that initializer file and there was some error with it so rails wouldn't even start the server:

```
ActiveSupport::CoreExtensions::Date::Conversions::DATE_FORMATS[:default] = '%m/%d/%Y'
```

**Question**: How can I make it so that when a date attribute is passed in the format of `%m/%d/%Y`: rails knows how to properly set that attribute and save the object successfully to the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would think about a custom setter in the model.

Assuming your date attribute is named `published_at` the setter could look like:

```
def published_at=(date_string)
  write_attribute(:published_at, Date.strptime(date_string, '%m/%d/%Y'))
end
```

Comment: Does rails automatically call this method when I call `Blog.new(blog_params)`? It is currently throwing an argument error: wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 2).  I tried looking at the docs on `#write_attribute` and am not quite sure how to grab that value and make it work when creating this object within the context of `accepts_nested_attributes` because this attribute will be passed differently within params. http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/Write/write_attribute